# Swift iOS Mask a string "Hello" to "Hxxxo"

Tags: ios, swift, string

```
extension String {
    var masked: String {
        // some logic which I have to write to mask string.

        // I tried following and just shows x ‍♂️
        // replacingOccurrences(
        //      of: ".(.+).", 
        //      with: "x", 
        //      options: .regularExpression, 
        //      range: nil
        //)
    }
}
let helloWorld = "Hello World"
print("Masked string is - \(helloWorld.masked)")
```

Expected output is - "Hxxxxxxxxxd"

Comment: I wonder why OP got two downvotes if he clearly showed his attempt to implement a solution

Comment: Can you please benchmark various answers eventually? Really interesting question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a Regular Expression way with *lookaround*

```
extension String {
    var masked: String {
        replacingOccurrences(
            of: "(?!^).(?!$)", // RegEx
            with: "x", // Replacement
            options: .regularExpression // Option to set RegEx
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can enumerate the string and apply map transform to get the expected output:

```
extension String {
  var masked: String {
    self.enumerated().map({ (index, ch) in
      if index == 0
        || index == self.count - 1 {
        return String(ch)
      }
      return "x"
    }).joined()
  }
}

let str = "hello"
print("after masking \(str.masked)") // Output - hxxxo
```

The map transform will return an array, so use `joined()` to convert the array back to String. Also, note that you have to typecast ch to String as `String(ch)` because the type of ch is 'String.Element' (aka 'Character').

Answer (score 3):

```swift
extension Sequence {
  func replacingEachInteriorElement(with replacement: Element) -> [Element] {
    let prefix = dropLast()
    return
      prefix.prefix(1)
      + prefix.dropFirst().map { _ in replacement }
      + suffix(1)
  }
}
```

```swift
extension String {
  var masked: Self {
    .init( replacingEachInteriorElement(with: "x") )
  }
}
```

```swift
"Hello World".masked == "Hxxxxxxxxxd" // true
"H‍♂️d".masked == "Hello World".masked // true
"".masked // 
"".masked // 
[].replacingEachInteriorElement(with: 500) // []
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution without using Regular Expression:

```
extension String {
    var masked: String {
        if self.count < 2 { return self }

        var output = self

        let range = self.index(after: self.startIndex)..<self.index(before: endIndex)

        let replacement = String.init(repeating: "x", count: output.count - 2)

        output.replaceSubrange(range, with: replacement)

        return output
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So far, I've found following solution.

```
extension String {
    var masked: String {
        var newString = ""
        for index in 0..<count {
            if index != 0 && index != count-1 {
                newString.append(contentsOf: "x")
            } else {
                let array = Array(self)
                let char = array[index]
                let string = String(char)
                newString.append(string)
            }
        }
        return newString
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave first and last letters you can use this ->

```swift
public extension String {

  var masked: String {
    return prefix(1) + String(repeating: "x", count: Swift.max(0, count-2)) + suffix(1)
  }
}
```

*USAGE*

```swift
let hello = "Hello"
hello.masked
// Hxxxo
```

**OR**

you can pass unmasked character count ->

```swift
public extension String {

  func masked(with unmaskedCount: Int) -> String {
    let unmaskedPrefix = unmaskedCount/2
    return prefix(unmaskedPrefix) + String(repeating: "x", count: Swift.max(0, count-unmaskedPrefix)) + suffix(unmaskedPrefix)
  }
}
```

*USAGE*

```swift
let hello = "Hello"
hello.masked(with: 2)
// Hxxxo

let number = "5555555555"
number.masked(with: 4)
// 55xxxxxx55
```